# Bash script to execute only on new files in directory

Tags: bash, perl, shell, unix, csv

I'm currently running a Bash script called (log2csv) that runs against a specified .log file. Sitting in the desired directory I can type in terminal:

`log2csv Red1_1.log`

This will create Red1_1.csv

This is my current bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for path
do
      base=$(basename "$path")
      noext="${base/.log}"
      /Users/joshuacarter/bin/read_scalepack.pl "$path" > "${noext}.csv"

done
```

This script is actually running a perl script on the specified log and putting the results in a CSV output.

I can alternatively run in terminal:

`log2csv *.log`

This will run the script against all .log files in the current directory and create .csv files for every one.

What I would like the script to do is only run on .log files that haven't had .csv files created for them. After doing some research I think I possibly can use [inotifywait](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes) to achieve this, but I'm unsure how to make this work in my script? I also have read that this may be an issue if you overwrite a file. Any help or ideas would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What I would like the script to do is only run on .log files that haven't had .csv files created for them.*

Simply skip those .log files whose corresponding .csv files already exist:

```
for path
do
      base=$(basename "$path")
      noext="${base/.log}"
      [ -e "${noext}.csv" ] && continue # <---------------
      /Users/joshuacarter/bin/read_scalepack.pl "$path" > "${noext}.csv"
done
```